# MySQL still show deleted rows

Tags: mysql, vb.net, phpmyadmin

I have a table with some deleted records, when i use PHPMYADMIN or DBeaver everything is OK, but with MySQL on VB.NET the deleted rows still show up, and of course causing problems.

I already updated the libraries of MySQL but the problem still exists.

Anyone knows what the problem might be?

Comment: Forgive me, but I have to ask. How are you deleting these rows. Can you show us some code please

Comment: No problem. I use the DELETE FROM [TABLE] WHERE ID=[SOMETHING]

Comment: Ok, so now what do you mean by "SHOW UP". Again can we see the code that is causing you a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I can answer the question myself, I flushed the table and everything looks fine now! So, if anyone comes to this problem just run:

FLUSH TABLE [TABLE_NAME];

And the problem will be fixed!

Comment: This doesn't sound right. I'm sure flushing can fix the issue, but it's a bit too expensive to make sure rows are deleted. It's a bit like saying "I restart the database every time I delete one row". The problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: The "problem" might be between using the .NET libraries and the PHP, side by side. Some people work with the software made with .NET, and other just use the webapp (the work done on both is different, so both are needed)